# Text disappears in Recyclerview when moved into AppBarLayout (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-appbarlayout

I am new to Android, but experienced at Java. Building a basic app and I want to add a RecyclerView (Found the tutorial for it [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-recyclerview-list-example)) along with the "Basic Activity" template layout.

When I add the RecyclerView in the XML, the items are hidden behind the top bar (first XML file and first Image), but when I move it to within the top bar, the text is removed (second XML file and second Image).

How do I fix this so that the text shows?

XML with RecyclerView under AppBarLayout

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Tasktrack.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Tasktrack.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        tools:context="com.github.heinrichwizardkreuser.tasktrack.MainActivity">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

XML with Recyclerview in AppBarLayout, but now text disappears

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Tasktrack.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Tasktrack.PopupOverlay" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            tools:context="com.github.heinrichwizardkreuser.tasktrack.MainActivity">
        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then the text becomes removed:
[image]

Comment: where is your item layout?

Comment: @NadimAnsari, you can find it under "list_item.xml" on the link provided (here it is again: https://www.javatpoint.com/android-recyclerview-list-example). Again, I literally took the code from above and implemented it with the Basic Activity template